Minimax Algorithm for tictactoe just plays in the next available square
I'm trying to learn the minimax algorithm. my minimax algorithm just doesn't work, The computer just plays "O" in the next available square. My entire source code is below (sorry for the wall of text). The bestScore variable stays at what it was initially set as (1000 or -1000 depending on if it was maximising or minimising) and it never returns one of the base cases. Not sure where to go from here
from json.encoder import INFINITY
from itertools import combinations

from pygame.examples import grid


class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [["-","-","-"],
                     ["-","-","-"],
                     ["-","-","-"]]

        self.MagicSquare = [[4, 9, 2],
                            [3, 5, 7],
                            [8, 1, 6]]

        self.XtoMove = True
        self.gameOver = False
        self.Xsum = []
        self.Osum = []
        self.Xwins = False
        self.Owins = False
        self.draw = False

    def makeMove(self, row, col):
        totalX = 0
        totalO = 0


        if self.grid[row][col] == "-":

            if self.XtoMove == True:

                self.grid[row][col] = 'X'
                self.bestMove()
                #self.XtoMove = False
                self.Xsum.append(self.MagicSquare[row][col])

                for combo in combinations(self.Xsum, 3):
                    if sum(combo) == 15:
                        self.gameOver = True
                        self.Xwins = True

            if len(self.Xsum) + len(self.Osum) == 9:
                self.gameOver = True
                self.draw = True



    def checkDraw(self):
        if len(self.Xsum) + len(self.Osum) == 9:
            self.gameOver = True
            self.draw = True
            return True

    def checkWinner(self, player):

        if player == 'X':
            sums = self.Xsum
        else:
            sums = self.Osum

        for combo in combinations(sums, 3):
            if sum(combo) == 15:
                return True
        return False


    def minimax(self, grid, depth, isMaximising):
        if self.checkWinner("O"):
            return 1
        elif self.checkWinner("X"):
            return -1
        elif self.checkDraw():
            return 0

        if isMaximising:
            bestScore = -1000
            for r in range(3):
                for c in range(3):
                    if grid[r][c] == "-":
                        grid[r][c] = 'O'
                        score = self.minimax(grid, depth + 1, False)
                        grid[r][c] = "-"
                        bestScore = max(score, bestScore)

            return bestScore

        else:
            bestScore = 1000
            for r in range(3):
                for c in range(3):
                    if grid[r][c] == "-":
                        grid[r][c] = 'X'
                        score = self.minimax(grid, depth + 1, True)
                        grid[r][c] = "-"
                        bestScore = min(score, bestScore)
            return bestScore

    def bestMove(self):
        bestScore = -10000
        move = (-1, -1)
        for r in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                if self.grid[r][c] == "-":
                    self.grid[r][c] = 'O'
                    score = self.minimax(self.grid, 0, False)
                    self.grid[r][c] = "-"
                    if score > bestScore:
                        bestScore = score
                        move = (r, c)

        if move != (-1,-1):
            self.grid[move[0]][move[1]] = 'O'
            self.Osum.append(self.MagicSquare[move[0]][move[1]])

            for combo in combinations(self.Osum, 3):
                if sum(combo) == 15:
                    self.gameOver = True
                    self.Owins = True

        if len(self.Xsum) + len(self.Osum) == 9 and not self.Owins:
            self.gameOver = True
            self.draw = True


Use a debugger to see where the first thing it does wrong is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The minimax function uses grid from an argument but bestMove uses self.grid. It's this lack of synchronicity that I believe may be causing your problem. I think it's that self.grid isn't being updated and instead just the argument grid is which then does not follow through.
I hope this helps.

But grid in the minimax function is just the parameter no?

Yeah, you're correct. My original answer was wrong, I see that now. But, if I'm not missing something obvious again, Xsum and Osum are not being updated in the minimax recursion loop which I assume may be why the base case is not being reached

Okay I see how that could cause some issues. So if I'm not mistaken, I would need to update Xsum and Osum, evaluate the score recursively, the pop the sum from the array?
